# Capybara click_link works wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing, poltergeist

I have such bug. Here is my code:

```
it "shows places sorted by date of creation" do
  click_button( I18n.t("models.places.actions.index.sort_by"))
  click_link(I18n.t("models.places.actions.index.date_of_creation"))

  sorted_places_names = places.map(&:name).reverse
  link_names = all("a.place-link").map(&:text)

  expect(link_names).to eq(sorted_places_names)
end
```

And my problem is that click link here must to send params: 
"`?by_created_at: true`" and controller response with sorted places by date of creation, in descendant order. 
My problem is when capybara clicks on this link, GET request have only path, without params needed.I`m using poltergeist here.

Also I have such test:

```
it "shows orders today" do
  today_order.customer.reputations << create(:reputation, place: place)

  visit place_statistics_loyalty_path(place)
  click_link(I18n.t("statistics.loyalty.today"))

  expect(page).to have_selector("#order_#{today_order.id}")
end
```

It tests out similar behaviour. And it works properly, but here I am not using js.
Is it javascript driver problem ?
Thanks. Sorry for bad text, it`s my first question.

Comment: Thank you for everybody, my problem was in that FactoryGirl generates records with identical created_at field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to do is use Poltergeist's "send_key" method as shown here in the documentation:

https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#sending-keys

Setting the keys using that method and then proceeding with clicking the link should work.

Comment: thank you but bug was in that Factory Girl generates record with identical created_at field, and that is my test fails.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're actually using poltergeist for that test since there is no `js: true` or `driver: :poltergeist` metadata on it?  If it was not using poltergeist and actually just using the rack_test driver then no JS would get excuted and you would likely see the behavior you're seeing.

If you are actually using the poltergeist driver then it's possible you have a race condition, due to click_button being asynchronous, which could cause the by_created_at parameter not to be set before the link click actually happens.  You can test if that is the issue by putting a `sleep 2` between the `click_button` and `click_link` calls

Comment: thank you but bug was in that Factory Girl generates record with identical created_at field, and that is my test fails.